# Type API variable-resolver is deprecated after JSF 1.1. Use el-resolver instead

Tags: java, jsf, websphere-portal, ibm-rad, ibm-jsf

We recently upgraded from WebSphere Portal v6.1 to v7.0 and in the process we now have JSF 1.2 available. Creating a new Portlet project in Rad 8 creates a faces-config.xml with the following entry

```
<application>
    <state-manager>com.ibm.faces.application.DevelopmentStateManager</state-manager>
    <variable-resolver>com.ibm.faces.portlet.PortletVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
</application>
```

And then complains: Type API variable-resolver is deprecated after JSF 1.1.  Use el-resolver instead.

Unfortunately i could not find an answer on the IBM pages which el-resolver to use.

Edit:

```
System.out.println("Resolver: " + PortalUtil.getFacesContext().getApplication().getELResolver());
```

=> Resolver: com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver@696e696e

Adding an entry in faces-config

```
<el-resolver>com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver</el-resolver>
```

With or without removing the variable-resolver leads to:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:270)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:358)
    ... 89 more
```

PMR with IBM opened ...

Comment: Is this of no help? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/javax/el/ELResolver.html

Comment: Warning message from RAD: Class javax.el.ELResolver must be concrete (not abstract).

Comment: We use Spring, and there is org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver. It works fine. Maybe try adding a dependency for this resolver? Put it like  <variable-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
        </variable-resolver>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBMs response to the PMR:

Q - What might be the consequences of ignoring the warning?

Ans - User can still use variable resolver, the functionality will not be affected. [This tag will be maintained for backwards compatibility]

Q - Why does the generated faces-config.xml still use the deprecated method ?

Ans - We are using variable resolver to resolve the portlet variables, which would work well even with JSF 1.2

Q - Will there be or is there an el-resolver for portlets?

Ans - There will be an el-resolver for portlets.  It will be provided in JSF portlet bridge 2.0 which will be shipped as an update to WAS.  It is currently in the planning stages so I cannot give you a precise version that this will be found in.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but if we're talking about an asynchronous web application, then you're dead in the water.

JSF 1.2 introduced a "known bug" (I always loved that phrase) is the `FaceletsRenderer` class that prevents you from asynchronously rendering JSF components (because all aynchronousity in JSF uses a *faked* `FacesContext`; not a functional one that can be used for rendering).  **You need JEE6-friendly JSF 2.1 for that**, otherwise you'll need a different solution altogether, as `@D1e` pointed out in his/her comment. Best of luck to your organization.

Comment: I'm confused, how asynchronous web apps could be related to the question. Especially since the stacktrace contains `FacesServlet.init` which is executed before any request processing.

Comment: Hm not using Facelets at all.